# get highest ids in multiple columns mysql sub query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This is the table i got:

```
id   userid  contactid
401     7   1
403     7   1
405     3   7
407     1   7
408     7   1
409     7   3 
410     3   7
411     7   1 
412     7   3 
413     7   4 
420     1   7 
423     7   1
```

What I'd like to get out from it is the highest id of userid or contactid when it's 7

```
SELECT id from table WHERE userid=7 OR contactid=7 
AND id NOT IN 
(SELECT id from table WHERE userid=7 OR contactid=7 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

This is what i've done, and it's not working.

In this query i want to recieve 3 rows and those are: (id)
412,413,423

Thanks !

Comment: sorry 3 of course, and as i wrote "What I'd like to get out from it is the highest id of userid or contactid when it's 7"

Comment: How do you decide that those are the three records you wish to return?  Why not id 409?

Comment: beecuase the highest id when userid=7 or contactid=7 is 423, (when contactid or userid also is 1)

Comment: @kilise . . . That explains 423, which makes sense.  What about 412 and 413?  Why those?  And why not 420?

Comment: Not really, why not get 420 as well. It's the highest where concatID is 7 ?

Comment: He wants to retrieve the last rows for each distinct contactid for userid 7

Comment: @Gordon Linoff... now we want the highest id from 7- 3 , 3- 7 which is 412... and the highest id is already found for 7-1 , 1 -7 in 423...

Comment: @Colandus: You must be psychic, because that's about as clear as mud to me.

Comment: @eggyal Well, userid 7 has 3 distinct contactid's: 1,3,4. He wishes to retrieve the latest rows from each of those. Which would be those he mentioned.

Comment: @Kilise . . . The key to understanding your question is that the pairs are unordered.  The names `userid` and `contactid` don't really convey that (and neither does the explanation).  If the names were `friend1` and `friend2` then all this discussion would not have happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, the interpretation of Colandus kind of makes sense:

```
select userid, contactid, max(id)
from t
where userid = 7
group by userid, contactid;
```

But, if I think of these as pairs with no ordering, then this version makes the most sense to me:

```
select least(userid, contactid), greatest(userid, contactid), max(id)
from t
where userid = 7 or contactid = 7
group by least(userid, contactid), greatest(userid, contactid)
```

When I think of the problem this way, the question starts to actually make sense.

Comment: the last example worked perfect , thanks a lot, and good work though there were a lots of confusment :D

Comment: +1, but I do think the easiest solution is to group by userid + contactid as I did in my reply :)

Comment: you dont have to group by `GREATEST(USERID, CONTACTID)`

Comment: @echo_me . . . You don't have to in this case because the limit is on value 7.  If the limit were on value 1, you would need that.  In addition, I think this formulation clarifies what the question is really about.

Answer (score 3):

Because either the userid or the contactid have to be 7, you can group by the added total of that column which would be distinct:

```
SELECT MAX(Id)
FROM yourtable
WHERE userid = 7 or contactid = 7
GROUP BY userid + contactid
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dac05/5)

Results:

```
MAX(ID)
423
412
413
```

Comment: `GROUP BY userid + contactid` would put `(3,5)` in the same group as `(2,6)`.

Comment: @eggyal -- correct, but one of the values has to be 7 -- that's what makes this work :)

Comment: Okay, but `(7,2)` will be in the same group as `(2,7)`.  Is that intentional too?

Comment: @eggyal -- that's my understanding of the OP's requirements -- those are the same so grab the highest Id of either.

Comment: Aah.  Maybe.  I think the OP's question is completely opaque, but you might be right.

Comment: great one this also works great

Comment: @Kilise -- no problem -- glad we could figure it out for you!

Comment: @Gordon Linoff What do you think about this solution? It seems easier than yours. Which one would you prefer in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try altering your query to SELECT MAX('id') - should do the trick
See also: [PHP MySQL max() function producing 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520773/php-mysql-max-function-producing-5)

Comment: I still don't see the 3 results? Two may be obvious enough but why 3?